# Setup Azure AD External Identity Provider for SSO with ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I know how to add external provider using .net Core Identity for Google, But i couldn't get any example to implement for Azure AD SSO using SAML2.So far i know we can use Sustainsys library to configure SAML2.

Exising code :

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    //Redirect to Login page
}
```

I have tried using Sustainsys library to implement , But there is no sample code or documentationusing ASP.NET identity.

Answer (score 1):

While the Sustainsys.Saml2 library can certainly be used with Azure AD, I'd recommend using the OpenID Connect packages from Microsoft that are built for Azure AD. They provide a better experience.